# URL regex that skips ending periods

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex that matches url strings within normal text.  I have this:

```
http[s]?://[^\s]+
```

This seems to work well with the exception that if the url is at the end of a sentence it will grab the period as well.  For example for this string:

I am typing some text with the url http://something.com/something-?args=someargs. This is another sentence.

it matches:

http://something.com/some-thing?args=someargs.

I would like it to match:

http://something.com/some-thing?args=someargs

Obviously I can't exclude periods because they are in the url previously but I can't figure out how to tell it to exclude the last period if there is one.  I could potentially use a negative lookahead for end of line or whitespace, but if it's in the middle of the line (without a period after it) that would leave off the last character of the url.

Most of the ones I have seen online have the same issue that they match the ending dot so maybe it's not possible?  I know basic regex but certainly not a genius with it so if someone has a solution I would be very grateful :).

Also, I can do some post-process in this case to remove the dot if I need to, just seems like there should be a Regex solution...

Comment: **Required reading:** https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-problem-with-urls/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one
`http[s]?://[^\s]+[^. ]`

Comment: Almost.  You forgot to escape the slashes.  https://regex101.com/r/lFOJxS/1

Comment: That seems to work thank you!  I did make one small mod for multiline text: http[s]?://[^\s]+[^.( \n)]

Comment: @RobertHarvey interesting, mine seemed to work without the escape for forward slashes but it doesn't on that site, any idea why?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Just change the delimiter. Use `#` or `~` for example.